# problem in excel while want to take the string in the left of comma

Tags: excel, exception

I have an excel file as the following: [image]

 I am trying to take the string in the left of the comma by using the function in the Redbox `=LEFT(A2;FIND(",";A2;1)-1)`. It worked well with the category that had a comma but I want if there is not a comma, It shows the string in the category instead of #value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when there it cant find the string its looking for, it throws an error. that makes everything looking at it throw an error.

try: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2,1)-1),A2)`

since the IFERROR will return "A2" instead of an error.

Comment: Tks <3 but while I use yours  It appears notice that There is a problem with this formula"
I will add it to the cmt above cuz the image can not upload in this zone :(

Comment: https://ibb.co/hCkM7SF here is the image... can you help me :(

Comment: I don't get that error. Under the formula tab, there should be a button called "evaluate formula". can you tell me where the code breaks?

Comment: I have noticed in your picture that in your Excel settings the sign to divide each element in a formula is semicolon (;) instead of comma (,). I would suggest to try the Doragon's formula as this: =IFERROR(LEFT(A2;FIND(",";A2;1)-1);A2)